# How exactly would the control flow graph look like for this code?

Tags: java, graph, control-flow

I'm trying to draw a control flow graph for this small piece of code so I can run a CC on it. I can't seem to grasp how to end the graph. Will there be another edge that goes from the while back to the top or the while to an exit node? If I draw an exit node and draw an edge to it, I get a CC of 2, but the analysis tool gives me a CC of 3. I made a graph but I can't post because I don't have enough rep.

```
public static void readCustomerData()
{
    int customerCount = 0;
    String customerNumber, cLastName, cFirstName; 
    double customerBalance;      

    while(masterFile.hasNext() && customerCount < MAX)
    {   
        statement1;
        statement2;
        statement3;
        statement4;
        statement5;
        statement6;
        statement7;
        increment statement++;        
    }
}
```